# How can I pass a Javascript ID value into window.location.href

Tags: javascript, html

The Latitude and longitude are displaying so I know the script is working up to the point of getting getting lat and lon.  My problem is passing the id value in the  window.location.href.  I get [object%20HTMLSpanElement] as my value.  here is the URL it takes me to "dummy website"
https://https://my_website/index.php?category=fast%20food&gps_geo_latitude=[object%20HTMLSpanElement]&gps_geo_longitude=[object%20HTMLSpanElement]. The point is to notice the values for geo_latitude and geo_longitude.  I have tried to add .value to variable like: var geo_longitude = document.getElementById('gps_geo_longitude').value; and when I do that the window.location.href does not appear to execute at all, and my span ID's do not display either.  Thanks for any help

```
<body onload="getLocation()">

<span id="gps_geo_longitude"></span>
<span id="gps_geo_latitude"></span>

<script>
var geo_longitude = document.getElementById('gps_geo_longitude');
var geo_latitude = document.getElementById('gps_geo_latitude');

function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
} else { 
  geo_longitude.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
}

function showPosition(position) {

geo_latitude.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;

geo_longitude.innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;

window.location.href = "https://my_website/index.php?category=fast%20food&gps_geo_latitude="  + gps_geo_latitude + "&gps_geo_longitude=" + gps_geo_longitude; 

}

function showError(error) {
switch(error.code) {
  case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
  geo_latitude.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
    break;
  case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
  geo_latitude.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
    break;
  case error.TIMEOUT:
  geo_latitude.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
    break;
  case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
  geo_latitude.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
    break;
}
}


 </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: How about using console.log to log the values of geo_latitude.innerHTML and geo_longitude.innerHTML and even the string you are about to put into window.location.href? This should give you a clue. Seems similar to something else I just saw today. Something about the event handler and your script variables being out of scope. Always better, I believe, NOT to use something like <body onload="something()"> and instead set up event handler in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `showPosition()` function you already have lat and long passed as `position` and you can use it directly like this

```
function showPosition(position) {
    geo_latitude.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
    geo_longitude.innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;

    window.location.href = "https://my_website/index.php?category=fast%20food&gps_geo_latitude="  + position.coords.latitude + "&gps_geo_longitude=" + position.coords.longitude; 
}
```

Or, you can get them from DOM the same way you set them in your `span`

```
function showPosition(position) {
    geo_latitude.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
    geo_longitude.innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;

    window.location.href = "https://my_website/index.php?category=fast%20food&gps_geo_latitude="  + geo_latitude.innerHTML + "&gps_geo_longitude=" + geo_longitude.innerHTML; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the first option works perfectly.  Problem solved.  But for your info the second option didn't work.  But what ever, I'm good to go.